# Python socket - how to save data from two clients separately

Tags: python, sockets

Here's the code, I wonder how to save the messages separately.

It can only get and send messages back to client. But I can't distinguish which are from client 1 and which are from client 2. Is there any way to save these messages into separate list or something else? so that I can distinguish them

Client 1:

```
import socket
import sys

messages = [b'This is client 1',
            b'It is a good day!',
            ] 

server_address = ('localhost', 1234) 
socks = [ socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, 
socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
for i in range(1)] 

print('connecting to %s port %s' % server_address) 
for s in socks:
    s.connect(server_address)

for message in messages:
    for s in socks:
        s.send(message)
    for s in socks: 
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(data.decode())
        if not data: 
            print(sys.stderr, 'closing socket', s.getsockname())
```

Client 2:

```
import socket
import sys

messages = [b'This is client 2',
            b'It is raining today',
            ] 

server_address = ('localhost', 5678) 
socks = [ socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, 
socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
for i in range(1)] 

print('connecting to %s port %s' % server_address) 
for s in socks:
    s.connect(server_address)

for message in messages:
    for s in socks:
        s.send(message)
    for s in socks: 
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(data.decode())
        if not data: 
            print(sys.stderr, 'closing socket', s.getsockname())
```

Server:

```
import selectors
import socket

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

def accept(sock, mask):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print('accepted', conn, 'from', addr)
    conn.setblocking(False)
    sel.register(conn, selectors.EVENT_READ, read)

def read(conn, mask):
    data = conn.recv(1000)
    if data:
        conn.send(data)
    else:
        print('closing', conn)
        sel.unregister(conn)
        conn.close()

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('localhost', int(input())))
sock.listen(1)
sock.setblocking(False)
sel.register(sock, selectors.EVENT_READ, accept)

while True:
    events = sel.select()
    for key, mask in events:
        callback = key.data
        callback(key.fileobj, mask)
```

Comment: client 2 is connecting to another server.

Comment: @mama sorry, I'll edit it now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the ip on the network layer then you can use the variable `addr` that you create when you accept the connection.

However when you are doing this with multiple clients on the same host then it will not work since the ip is the same.

This will also not work if you are behind a NAT, because you would just get the IP of the nearest router in your network.

Another solution would be to validate the client on the application layer and simply give the client an identification value that you pass into the message that you send from the client.

Comment: If the clients have different ip and server get ip from input, is it possible?

Comment: Yes if you are not behind a NAT - check https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept